# Determinant of the curved space scalar wave operator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I am reading a paper titled 'Analogue Gravity' (http://www.livingreviews.org/lrr-2011-3 or http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0505065) In the paper (page 15/159) they say this:

$$\det(\sqrt{-g} g^{\mu \nu}) = (\sqrt{-g})^4 g^{-1} = g\tag{30}$$

I am having trouble seeing how this is obtained, in particular, where does the $g^{-1}$ term come from? And why is there no minus sign?

I thought the answer would be this:

$$\det(\sqrt{-g} g^{\mu \nu}) = \det\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-\sqrt{-g} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{-g} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{-g} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{-g}
\end{array}\right) = -(\sqrt{-g})^4 = -g^2$$

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Having said that, the point is that $g^{\mu\nu}$ is not the identity matrix, but the inverse of the metric.

Answer (score 2):

$g^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$; and the expression is for a general metric, not for the Minkowski metric.

In 4 dimensions, if $g = \det(g_{\mu\nu})$
$$\det(\sqrt{-g} g^{\mu\nu}) = (\sqrt{-g})^4\det(g^{\mu\nu}) = \frac{g^2}{\det(g_{\mu\nu})} = g$$

Comment: Ok treating it as a general metric makes sense. However I am still not sure how you have evaluated $\det(\sqrt{-g}g^{\mu \nu})$ to obtain the $(\sqrt{-g})^4$ term. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Its a constant to the power of the matrix order.